# Posting Json data to controller

Tags: .net, json, model-view-controller

I am new to .Net MVC. I am trying to send some data from my view to the controller.

Controller Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(string json)
    {
        //more code here
    }
```

JS:

```
function SaveDetails() {
     var details= {
    "Code": "test",
    "Desc": "Testing",
    "Xclude": "N"
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "Add",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(details),
    success: function (){
                $('#Code').val("");
                $('#Desc').val("");
                $('#Xclude')[0].checked = false;
    }
    });
```

}

But when I debug the code, the variable json in the controller is getting null value and not the data I am passing to it. I am not able to identify what is wrong here.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data: {json:JSON.stringify(details)}
```

Otherwise MVC is going to expect the parameter name to be `id`.

Comment: @Patrick...thanks for ur response...but even after the change the variable value is still null.